# Can't inject by qualifier

Tags: java, spring, proxy

I have custom annotation named Retry with following Bean Post Processor:

```
@Component
public final class RetryBPP implements BeanPostProcessor {

    private final Map<String, ClassDefinition> map = new HashMap<>(40);

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {
        final Class<?> asClass = bean.getClass();
        final Method[] methods = asClass.getMethods();
        final List<Method> collect = Stream.of(methods)
                .filter(method -> method.isAnnotationPresent(Retriable.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        if(!collect.isEmpty()){
            this.map.put(beanName,new ClassDefinition(collect,asClass));
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {
        final ClassDefinition definition = this.map.get(beanName);
        if(definition != null){
            final Class beanClass = definition.baseCLass;
            return Proxy.newProxyInstance(beanClass.getClassLoader(), beanClass.getInterfaces(), (proxy, method, args) -> {
                if(definition.isMethodPresent(method)){
                    return this.retry(definition.originalMethod(method),bean,args);
                } else{
                    return method.invoke(bean,args);
                }
            });
        } else{
            return bean;
        }
    }

    private Object retry(final Method method,final Object originalBean,Object[] argc){
        final Retriable retriable = method.getAnnotation(Retriable.class);
        int attempts = retriable.attempts();
        while(true){
            try{
                return method.invoke(originalBean,argc);
            }catch (final Exception throwable){
                if(this.support(retriable.exceptions(),throwable.getClass()) && attempts != 0){
                    attempts--;
                    log.warn("Error on method {} wait to repeat",method.getName());
                    this.sleep(retriable.delay(),retriable.timeUnit());
                } else{
                    throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @SneakyThrows(InterruptedException.class)
    private void sleep(final long time, final TimeUnit timeUnit){
        timeUnit.sleep(time);
    }

    private boolean support(final Class<? extends Exception>[] exceptions,Class<? extends Exception> exception){
        boolean support = false;
        for (Class _class : exceptions) {
            if(_class.equals(exception)){
                support = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return support;
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    private static final class ClassDefinition{
        final List<Method> methods;
        final Class baseCLass;

        boolean isMethodPresent(final Method method){
            return this.methods.stream()
                               .anyMatch(mthd->methodEquals(mthd,method));
        }

        Method originalMethod(final Method method){
            return this.methods.stream()
                               .filter(mthd->methodEquals(mthd,method))
                               .findFirst().orElseThrow(NullPointerException::new);

        }

    }

}
```

Interface:

```
public interface Inter {

    String qqq(String url);

}
```

Abstract class:

```
public abstract class Abs implements Inter {

    @Override
    @Retry
    public String qqq(final String url) {
        someLogic(url);
    }

  protected String someLogic(String str);
```

Custom qualifier annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
@Target({ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface Qualif {

    VV.v type();

}
```

And implementation:

```
@Service
@Qualif(type = First)
@Slf4j
public final class Impl extends Abs {

   @Override
   protected String someLogic(String str){...}
}
```

And when I autowire by qualifier like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualif(type = First)
Inter inter;
```

Spring throw exception `No qualifying bean of type [com.devadmin.downloader.sites.VideoDownloader] found for dependency Inter`:, but when I remove @Retry annotation from abctract class everything work cool. How to solve this issue.

BTW I checked that my class that extend Abstract class inside `ApplicationContext` but Spring didn't see my custom qualifier

Comment: Have you checked your context scan packages? I mean, check if your configuration is exposing your Retry class as a spring bean, if not try by defining it as a bean. Hope this helps

Comment: @FranciscoValle everything work as expected when I Remove Retry annotation from abstract class

Comment: What exception is spring throwing when you include the Retry annotation?

Comment: @FranciscoValle edit question

Answer (score 1):

Finally I find an answer. For those who didn't understand the problem.

I have an interface with method `foo()` ,  then an abstract class that implements this interface and has own abstract method

```
abstract class FooAbs impl Inter{
   @Override 
   void foo(){
      childMethod();
    }
   protected void childMethod();
}
```

And finally I have class with @Component that extends FooAbs class.

```
@Component 
class First extends FooAbs{

  @Override
  void childMethod(){}
}
```

The problem was with dynamic proxy.

This code from below wasn't able to get interfaces from class

```
Proxy.newProxyInstance(beanClass.getClassLoader(), beanClass.getInterfaces(), (proxy, method, args) -> {}
```

Dynamic proxy doesn't see `getInterfaces` of `First` class because this class doesn't implement interface directly,  therefore I changed my class signature to this:

```
@Component 
    class First extends FooAbs implement Inter{
    
      @Override
      void childMethod(){}
    }
```

After this step

```
beanClass.getInterfaces()
```

sees Inter interface. I know that it's a work around  and I will rewrite my code to avoid such structure. But it works and maybe for some one it will be helpful